# C# Webcontrol class inheritance/modification

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, webforms

I'm working on a project in which I must create a dynamic web form based on many different variables. I'm attempting to create a class called "MyControl" derived from the existing Web.UI.WebControls, and add member variables such as "parameterByteSize," etc.

The goal is to then be able to instantiate a "MyControl" object with custom information, as well as the functionality of the methods of a generic WebControl.

The problem that I'm running into is that I want to be able to create a TextBox, a type of WebControl, while also maintaining the custom members that I added to my original derived class.

```
MyControl control = new TextBox()
```

The code above returns an error, saying that a TextBox cannot be converted to the type "MyControl" I understand that both MyControl and TextBox are derived from WebControls, and therefore can't be converted to each other, but what can I do to instantiate a TextBox WebControl while also maintaining the custom members that I added in MyControl?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just add web controls needed for your Form into class MyControl, so if MyControl should have a textbox, a drop down and a button, add properties to MyControl of types TextBox, Select and Button.

Comment: Do you mean add those options as derived classes of MyControl? How will it gain the functionality of the WebControl versions of those classes. AKA how will TextBox : MyControl  gain the functionality of TextBox : WebControls?

Comment: No I mean add a Texbox as a class property of MyControl. Like my example below.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!